# Find a formula for the binomial coefficients of the Macluarin series for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/2}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, taylor-expansion

The Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/2}}$ is 
\begin{equation*}
1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}-\frac{5x^3}{16}+\frac{35x^4}{128}...~. 
\end{equation*}
I can't figure much out other than it appears there is a factor of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ involved for the coefficients.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice
$$\begin{align}
(1+x)^\alpha &= 1 +  \alpha + \alpha(\alpha-1) \frac{x^2}{2!} + \alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2) \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)\right) \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
\implies \frac{1}{(1+x)^\alpha}
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha+k)\right) \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
\implies
\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/2}}
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac12\right)^n\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\right) \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align}
$$
This leads to
$$
\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/2}}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} x^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2} x^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^r$ is $$(-1)^r\frac {(2r)!}{2^{2r}(r!)^2}$$

Comment: Great formula, +1.  So the expansion of $(1-4x)^{-1/2}$ is really neat.

Comment: Yes. Now the coefficient of $x^r$ is the same as the number of distinguishable permutations of $r$ Xs and $r$ Ys in a line. I wonder what the connection is?